# How do you make this.forceUpdate() apply to entire app in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rendering

I have a React Native app in which I want to place a button that appears on every screen that the user can click to force a re-render (using `this.forceUpdate()`). On every screen I have a custom `<Header>` component at the top, and I want to put the re-render button in that header since it appears on every screen, and I'd therefore have to add the button only once.

So one of my screens would look like this:

```
export default class Screen1 extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <Header>
        ...rest of screen...
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

And `Header` looks like this

```
export default class Header extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => this.forceUpdate()}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Clicking the `<TouchableOpacity>` in the Header causes the Header itself to update, but not the entire screen. I assume `this.forceUpdate()` applies only to the component in which the `<TouchableOpacity>` is defined. So my question is, **is there any equivalent of `this.forceUpdate()` that I can call in my header that will force a re-render of the entire screen?**

Thanks!

Comment: I would advise against it. There is no need to force update the app. All you need to do is to update the props or state, depends on your architecture. If you want to apply the render whatever in your custom header in all screens, I would use https://redux.js.org. You can create an action which would update the app state. You just connect the `Header` to the store and it will handle the re-render by itself because the props have changed.

Comment: @parohy Thanks for your Redux suggestion. I'm already using Redux heavily in the app so I'll try to find a solution using it.
I know that what I was asking is a bad idea in general. This is a temporary hack. Hot reloading hasn't been working, and I've spent too much time trying to fix it, so I'm making a temporary hack in order to be able to do some quick UI updates to meet a deadline, and then will keep digging into the root of the problem (and remove the hack) afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @parohy suggested it's not the way to go.. at all.
But has a temporary hack you can pass `this.forceUpdate()` as props to the header.
would look like this:

```
 export default class Screen1 extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <Header forceUpdate={this.forceUpdate}>
        ...rest of screen...
      </View>
    )
  }
}
export default class Header extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => this.props.forceUpdate()}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```